# Scala's Source.fromURL over http proxy

Tags: scala, jvm, http-proxy

I couldn't read from URL in scala over an http proxy.

I have this code

```
//This is just to print the environment
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
println(System.getProperties.filter(_._1 startsWith("http")).toList sortBy(_._1) mkString "\n")

import scala.io.Source
val html = Source.fromURL("http://google.com")
val s = html.mkString
println(s)
```

I get the following error

```
(http.proxyHost,158.169.9.13)
(http.proxyPassword,*****)
(http.proxyPort,8012)
(http.proxyUser,*****)
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: http://google.com
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1612)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1035)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromURL(Source.scala:143)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromURL(Source.scala:133)
        at Main$$anon$1.<init>(download.scala:7)
        at Main$.main(download.scala:1)
        at Main.main(download.scala)
```

I was expecting a print of the google.com page source.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try Source.fromURL(new java.net.URL("myURL")) API ? The code looks something along these lines:

```
 val response: String = try {
      val proxy: Proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080))
      val connection: HttpURLConnection = new java.net.URL("myURL").openConnection(proxy).asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
      connection.connect()
      Source.fromInputStream(connection.getInputStream).getLines.mkString
    }
    catch {
      case e: Throwable => "" // Do whatever you want here: logging/throw exception/..
    }
```